# Regex that excludes input strings with specific numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I have the following 4 inputs:

```
{168,3816,2012,[04,14]}
{168,38087,2012,[14,32]}
{168,37955,2012,[14,32]}
{168,33409,2011,[14]}
```

I want to exclude the input 4 since it has the number 33409 after the first comma, so my final result will be:

```
{168,3816,2012,[04,14]}
{168,38087,2012,[14,32]}
{168,37955,2012,[14,32]}
```

I came up with the following regex `.*,(?!(33409))\d{5},.*` but it failed to include the first input:
{168,3816,2012,[04,14]}, and this is because I am specifying the range d{5}. Using \d+ or \d{0,5} doesn't work.

I would like my regex to be able to exclude multiple numbers, for example inputs with numbers 33409 or 3816 after first comma. So the final result will be:

```
{168,38087,2012,[14,32]}
{168,37955,2012,[14,32]}
```

---

Thank you all for your feedbacks. 
I realized that I needed to give more details of the problem to get the correct answer.
Here's a detailed explanation of the problem. I have a list of books titles with metadata attached.
The meta data consist of `ItemClass,Itemkey,ItemPublicationyear and ItemCategory`. The book titles are 
returned in the following format:

```
booktitle {itemclass,itemkey,itempublicationyear,[itemcategory]} 
//ItemCategory can have mult. values
```

Filters in the form of REGEX, are applied to the metadata within {} to return the correct titles to the user.

sample list of books titles will look like this:

```
Business Liability Insurance  2011-12 {168,326,2011,[14,32]}   //itemcategory with mult. values
Insurance Regulation 2013 {168,37955,2012,[14,32]}
Financial Institutions  {168,33734,2011,[14]} //itemcategory with just one value
Insider Trading Law {168,32645,2011,[04,14]}
Business Liability Insurance {168,32647,2011,[14,32,45]}
```

A user request can consist of one or more filters.
For example, 
user may request a list of book titles that belong to itemclasses 102,33,168 so the REGEX will
look like this:

```
(102|33|168),(.*),(.*),(.*) //I didn't use (102|33|168),(.*) because I want 
the format of the expression to be ItemClass,ItemKey,ItemPublicationYear,ItemCategory


Another request with filter  ItemCategory= 14 will look like this: (.*),(.*),(.*),\[(((\d+),)*(14)(,\d+)*)\]

If user applied both the ItemClass and ItemCategory filters the regex will look like this:
(102|33|168),(.*),(.*),\[(((\d+),)*(14)(,\d+)*)\]
```

I kind of get it to work for all filters. I get stuck for cases when user wants to use filter to exclude specific 
books by applying the itemkey filter, so user can request
all books titles except for books with itemkeys 32647,326

```
Itemclasses     Itemkey         ItemPublicationYear    ItemCategory     Regex
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    All         All             All                     All             (.*),(.*)(.*),(.*)      //no filters applied
    110,112     All             All                     All             (110|112),(.*),(.*),(.*)
    All         38524           All                     All             (.*),(38524),(.*),(.*)
    All         All             2004-2014               All             (.*),(.*),2(0(0([4-9])|1([0-4]))),(.*)
    All         All             All                    24,21,27         (.*),(.*),(.*),\[(((\d+),)*(24|21|27)(,\d+)*)\]
    110,112     38524           All                    24,21,27         (110|112),(38524),(.*),\[(((\d+),)*(24|21|27)(,\d+)*)\]
```

Comment: How will the numbers ultimately be parsed?

Answer (score 0):

The end result that you want is not properly explained?

Are each of the above inputs strings?

> "{168,3816,2012,[04,14]}" 
>   "{168,38087,2012,[14,32]}"
>   "{168,37955,2012,[14,32]}" 
>    "{168,33409,2011,[14]}"
>   Could you answer the below questions?
>   What exactly do u want to match?
>   Do you want to check if the first number after first comma to not be equal to 33409?
>   
> "I would like my regex to be able to exclude multiple numbers"=>What do you mean multiple numbers here?

However from my understanding try the below reg ex

> /{\d{3}\,(?:!(?:33409|3816))\,\d{4},[\d+\,\d+]}

This will try to match

```
{3 digit no, not equal to 33409 or 3816, 4digit no, [any digit no, any digit no]}
```